# Codeigniter not displaying updated record

Tags: codeigniter, caching, sql-update

I'm using latest version of `CI` for my project. I've a list of companies shown to the admin at `backend`, which show their information. The companies register from `frontend` and then show in the list for approval/disapproval from admin.

Now coming to the question. If I approve or disapprove any particular company, it updates the record in `database`, but as soon as redirects back to the list page, it shows the previous `status` of the company i.e it doesn't display the new updated status.

But as soon as I refresh the page, the new status is displayed. It comes to my mind that it may be fetching values from cache.

I'm using CI native function to update such as `$this->db->update('companyTable', $data)`

Can any one point me in the right direction, as to what I'm doing wrong here.

**NOTE:** Updation occurs in db, but when redirected back it shows old status. Upon refresh it shows new updated status.

**NOTE2:** It only happens on live server. On localhost it is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you may use refresh during redirect
like `redirect('controller/function','refresh');`

Comment: I'm already using `redirect('controller/function','refresh');`